# Popular algorithms for recognition of this image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-matching, image-recognition, identification

I have some image like following image:
         [image]

I have developed my own algorithm to find corresponding image to test image in my DB.

My problem is that I want to compare my algorithm with well-known algorithms. Since my pattern is kind of unique I have no Idea about well-known algorithm which works for me.

1. Anybody has any suggestion about type of image processing algorithm that works for me?
2. Any other suggestion for measuring my algorithm performance?

Answer (score 0):

As no-one is answering, I will make a first attempt and maybe that will spur others into action.

My initial reaction would be to look a *Fingerprint Recognition* techniques which analyse ridge endings (line ends), bifurcations (junctions) and short ridges, loops and whorls. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fingerprint_recognition).

This can be done readily at the command line with **ImageMagick** and there are some excellent techniques written up by Anthony Thyssen [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/morphology/#skeleton_info). There are Perl, PHP, Python, Java, C/C++ bindings too if you prefer those languages.

So, let's look at line endings. You can find the line endings like this:

```
convert dendrite.png -threshold 50% -morphology HMT LineEnds result.png
```

[image]

And you can put red circles around them like this:

[image]

And you can count them like this:

```
convert dendrite.png -threshold 50% -morphology HMT LineEnds -format "%[fx:mean*w*h]" info:
59
```

Anthony goes on to look at junctions and loops, but get it straight from the maestro...

Hope that helps. How about sharing your own technique?